# Android: Custom Expandeble List and TextView issue

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, textview, expandablelistview

I faced with one issue when I tried to create my custom Expandable List View.
I can't make text ("9.2") on the center of the cell.

[incorrect image](http://tinypic.com/r/3586gqv/8)

But on the prevew mode it looks fine.

[correct image](http://i61.tinypic.com/mn16at.jpg)

Here my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_between_elements"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rate">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bigTitle"
            style="@style/PrimaryFont"
            android:text="A big title"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/littleTitle"
            style="@style/SecondaryFont"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_between_elements"
            android:text="A little title" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        style="@style/RatingFont"
        android:text="9.2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titles" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/touchable_ui_components"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/titles" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think the main issue due to +id/image becasue without +id/titles it  also looks incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the TextView with id rate.

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Remove

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Be careful with the padding, it might move the drawable region not be in the center. (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html ->Size, padding and margins)

Also these two:

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

have similar effects, use only one. I prefer Right
(see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_END)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the main issue was due to padding. When I removed all limks with bottom and top and use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` like you suggested it will work